# Get Avg for this query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let’s say I have a table with the following columns:
`EmployeeID, PayEntity, HourWorked, Date` where `PayEntity can be 1:Normal, 2:OverTime, etc` How can I get the average of Hours worked for a period of time for example if we do have on my table those data:

```
1, 1, 40, 7/25/12
1, 2, 5, 7/25/12
2, 1, 30, 7/25/12
```

The average for this date must be `(40+5)+30/2 --  37.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a subselect where you find the total hours for each employee per day, and an outer select where you calculate the average per day:

```
SELECT Date, AVG(HourWorked) AS HourWorked
FROM 
(
    SELECT Date, SUM(HourWorked) AS HourWorked
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY EmployeeId, Date
) T1
GROUP BY Date
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be733/1)

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines, but didn't know there was an AVG function

```
SELECT employee_id, total_hours, days, total_hours/days as average, 
FROM (
    SELECT employee_id, SUM(hours) as total_hours, COUNT(date) as days FROM `employee_hours_table` GROUP BY `employee_id`
) data
```